# How to setup Multiple countdown timers on products?

Tags: javascript, html

Setting up a sales page and I can't get the product inventory countdown timer to work on other products on the page.

I got it working for the first product but it doesn't wanna work on the second product. Same Page.

```js
// Random Countdown Timer Script, by http://ctrtard.com
var timer;


function startCount() {
  timer = setInterval(count, 200); // 200 = 200ms delay between counter changes. Lower num = faster, Bigger = slower.
}

function count() {
  var rand_no = Math.ceil(9 * Math.random()); // 9 = random decrement amount. Counter will decrease anywhere from 1 - 9.
  var el = document.getElementById('counter');
  var currentNumber = parseFloat(el.innerHTML);
  var newNumber = currentNumber - rand_no;
  if (newNumber > 0) {
    el.innerHTML = newNumber;
  } else {
    el.innerHTML = "Sold Out"; // This message is displayed when the counter reaches zero.
  }
}
```

```html
<body onLoad="startCount();">

  <span class="timer">Buy it now!!!!!! only <span id="counter">15555</span> left</span>

</body>
```

I just end up with one timer or the other working, not both firing off

Comment: I'm working off of this https://codepen.io/DavidWells/pen/cotHl

Comment: you have to use different id for different products

Comment: An `id` is supposed to be unique. You most likely simply copied the `<span>` to your second product. The `count` function however will ignore it, even if it could magically tell that you want it to address the 2nd counter when called from within `startCount2`.

Comment: I'm pretty new to coding. Could you give me an example of how I could Id the code for two different products?

Comment: FYI these sort of misleading/high-pressure/aggressive sales tactics are illegal in many jurisdictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is have 2 unique ids for your counters (let's say counter1 and counter2) and then, update those in your `count` method like that:

```
<span class="timer">Buy it now!!!!!! only <span id="counter1">15555</span> left</span>
...
<span class="timer">Buy it now!!!!!! only <span id="counter2">12345</span> left</span>
```

```
var timer;
var nbCounters = 2;

function startCount() {
  timer = setInterval(count, 200); // 200 = 200ms delay between counter changes. Lower num = faster, Bigger = slower.
}

function count() {
  // Update all counters
  for(i=1; i<=nbCounters; i++) {
    var rand_no = Math.ceil(9 * Math.random()); // 9 = random decrement amount. Counter will decrease anywhere from 1 - 9.
    var el = document.getElementById('counter' + i);
    var currentNumber = parseFloat(el.innerHTML);
    var newNumber = currentNumber - rand_no;
    if (newNumber > 0) {
      el.innerHTML = newNumber;
    } else {
      el.innerHTML = "Sold Out"; // This message is displayed when the counter reaches zero.
    }
  }
}
```

I'd really advise you to have a look at jQuery for DOM manipulation: https://api.jquery.com/

Lucas

Comment: Appending running numbers to `id`s is bad practice; you should use a suitable array and a class instead.